# Add custom attribute to waterline model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Since nested population isn't available I need to pass my custom attributes manually. In my specific case this means: a customer has many projects, a project has many contributors.

```
Customer.find().populate('projects').exec(function(err, customer) {
```

Response looks like

```
[
    {
        "projects": [
            { "name": "First project" }
        ],
        "customer": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "projects": [
            { "name": "Another project" },
            { "name": "And another one" }
        ],
        "customer": "Susan Doe"
    }
]
```

I'm iterating through the projects and want to attach a `contributors` attribute. I've tried

```
customer.forEach(function(customer, index) {
    customer.projects.forEach(function(project, index) {
        ProjectContributor.find({
            project: project.id
        }).exec(function(err, contributor) {
            project.contributors = contributors;
        });
```

But `project.contributors` is still undefined. Why? And how to attach these custom attributes?

Answer (score -1):

There are many errors in you code.

```
Customer.find().populate('projects').exec(function(err, customers) {
  customers.forEach(function(customer, index) {
    customer.projects.forEach(function(project, index) {
      ProjectContributor.findOne({project: project.id}) // use findOne since you only want one project at a time
      .populate('contributors')
      .exec(function(err, projectContributor) {
        project.contributors = projectContributor.contributors; // contributors is in projectContributor
      });
    });
  });
});
```